# Automatically compiling asymptote on vim, with .asy files in another directory?

Tags: asymptote, latexmk, auxiliary-files, vim

I am currently using latex on vim with the vimtex plugin (with mac big sur os), and there are two features I would like to have:

1. Asymptote compiles automatically when I compile latex
2. All auxiliary files (.aux, .fls, etc. and also asymptote files like file-1.asy, file-1.pdf etc.) would be organized in a separate "build" directory

In my .vimrc file, I have the following specified under the vimtex plugin, which moves all auxiliary files (.aux, .fls, etc. as well as the .asy files) to a separate "build" directory.

```
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
    let g:tex_flavor='latex'
    let g:vimtex_view_method='skim'
    let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
    let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
                \ 'build_dir' : 'build',
                \}
    set conceallevel=1
    let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'
```

The asymptote files (file-1.asy, file-1.pdf, etc.) are automatically moved to the build directory as desired. However, the asymptote doesn't compile automatically when latex is compiled.

So, in my .latexmkrc file, I have the following which enables the asy to automatically compile when I compile the tex document (successfully).

```
sub asy {return system("asy \"$_[0]\"");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

However, this only works when I *don't* specify the build directory in the .vimrc file, i.e. when working with conjunction with the following line, it fails.

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = {
            \ 'build_dir' : 'build',
            \}
```

Essentially, I am able to get each of the two features I desire on their own, but I can't get both to work at the same time. Is there any way I can have both features work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into this issue too on Linux.

In your `.latexmkrc`, use

```
sub asy {return system("asy -outname \$(dirname '$_[0]')/build '$_[0]'");}
```

instead of

```
sub asy {return system("asy \"$_[0]\"");}
```

It might be a good idea to configure the build directory of `latexmk` directly in your `.latexmkrc` instead of `.vimrc` with

```
$out_dir="build";
```

This way we can instead do

```
sub asy {return system("asy -outname \$(dirname '$_[0]')/$out_dir '$_[0]'");}
```